# Cannon.js - Visualise body velocity path

Tags: three.js, game-physics, cannon.js

I'm using Cannon.js with Three.js.

I have a basic scene which on mouse click adds a sphere to Three.js & Cannon.js. The sphere has a velocity set of 100, and Cannon.js simulates the path the sphere takes, from point A to point B.

Is there a way to simulate this force and draw a line from point A (sphere starting position) to point B (sphere end position after velocity is applied)?

Or instead of simulating this, a way to calculate the path the sphere will take based on the velocity?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that neither `cannon.js` or `three.js` has a vector class. Luckily I designed an example that should show you how to implement one into whatever you're working on [here](https://repl.it/@Trixter/Vector-Example).

The example basically scales a vector object in accordance to the cube's velocity. It updates this every time all other physics are updated.

Comment: FYI, *BOTH* [ThreeJS](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3) and [Cannon](https://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/docs/classes/Vec3.html) have extremely useful Vector classes (particularly the former).